# JavaScript fetching local json file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I've got this code set and a json file called statistics.json but when I log the data it says data is not defined

Anyone knows how to solve this?

```
const showStatistics = function(){
    fetch("../assets/statistics.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {data.stats})
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: There's a strange line in your code: `{data.stats}`. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: shows stats array of the data of the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log `data` inside callback at `then`, because it is asynchronous.

```js
const showStatistics = function(){
    fetch("../assets/statistics.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

    
}
```